# Python remove element in list

Tags: python

I have a question

say I have two list, and each of them contains couple of strings

```
a = ['x', 'y', 'z', 't'] b = ['xyz', 'yzx', 'xyw']
```

I want to delete `xyw` in list b, because `w` is not in list `a`.

I tried

```
for s in a:
    k = [t for t in b if t.find(s)]
```

but it didn't work
Does anyone know how to do this in Python? Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry but as SO is not a *do it for me* site you need to show us that what you have tried so far! then we can help you on your problems!

Comment: @KasraAD thanks for your reminder, I just join this website. I did have a try, I changed my question.

Comment: welcome! OK, always remember that as you explain more about your question as you get a complete answer!

Answer (score 3):

You could check that all of the letters in each string are contained in your list `a` then filter out strings using a list comprehension.

```
>>> a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> b = ['xyz', 'yzx', 'xyw']
>>> [i for i in b if all(j in a for j in i)]
['xyz', 'yzx']
```

Comment: Great! But if a = ['x', 'y', 'z', 't'], how to change the code? thanks!

Comment: I tried , but the answer is [] ... I also tried [i for i in b if any(j in i for j in a)], the answer is ['xyz', 'yzx', 'xyw'] ...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> b = ['xyz', 'yzx', 'xyw']
>>> for element in b:
...     if not all(i in a for i in element):
...         b.remove(element)
... 
>>> b
['xyz', 'yzx']
>>>
```

Correcttion: I shouldn't delete during iterating. So following like the solution above fits

```
>>> a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> b = ['xyz', 'yzx', 'xyw']
>>> b = [i for i in b if all(j in a for j in i)]
>>> b
['xyz', 'yzx']
>>>
```

Comment: This fails for e.g. `b = ['xyz', 'yzx', 'xyw', 'xyq']`, because you're removing items from the list as you iterate over it.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Oh, I got. I shouldn't do that. I should follow the above solution and reassign to b. Is that correct?