# Python: what is the good practice to remove all elements in the list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have simple list and I want to remove all elements one by one. Here is the simplified version:

```
lst=[2,5]
for i in lst:
    print(i)
    lst.remove(i)
```

It only remove 2 but element 5 remain.
I know the reason as it has been answered in [cannot remove the last element of a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058889/cannot-remove-the-last-element-of-a-python-list) and in [Python remove element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565973/python-remove-element-in-list). I also know it might be a bad practice. However both Q/A did not offer the alternative solution what is the good practice to solve this problem. Any help?

Comment: Use `lst.clear()`.  If you need Python 2 support as well, use `del lst[:]`.

Comment: The solution I do is to create another list to accumulate what I want to remove and then remove them outside the loop.
lst=[2,5]
lst2=[]
for i in lst:
 print(i)
 lst2.append(i)
for j in lst2:
 lst.remove(j)

Comment: Thank you this is the solution that I was looking for